# Issue with has_and_belongs_to_many association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Can you help a noob, please?
I have 2 models - Player and Poker Tables, which have has_and_belongs_to_many association. When i try create player i catch error

> undefined method `poker_table'

```
respond_to do |format|
      **if @player.save**
        format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @player }
      else
```

I use checkboxes for mark needed poker tables, here form code:

```
<% @poker_tables = PokerTable.all %>
        <% @poker_tables.each do |poker_table| %>
        <div>
            <%= check_box_tag "player[poker_table_ids][]", poker_table.id %>
            <%= poker_table.name %>
            <%= poker_table.actual_time %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

create method and params

```
def create
@player = Player.new(player_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @player.save
    format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @player }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
```

end

```
def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:email, :poker_table_ids => [])
end
```

I can create poker table, but couldn't create a player with associated poker tables.
I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. I studied a lot of resources about this theme, but i can't find answer.

Comment: Can you post full error stacktrace in the question?

Comment: I can't see anything in the code included here that would cause that error.  Can you please edit your question and include a) the associations between Player & PokerTable and b) any callbacks (before_save etc) you have on the Player model.  Also add the stack trace, as @Pavan says - the stack trace will point you to the error: look for the first line in the stack trace which refers to your code, rather than to a gem or something.

Comment: Thanks for help, i found my fail in Player model, where i associate validation with poker table model. Sorry for my bad language:)
P.S. `validates_associated :poker_table, :message => "You can assign only to 6 poker tables."` - this line of code ruined my app)